# Trouble with Joda Time JSP tags

Tags: java, apache, jsp, jodatime

I am writing a web-app which utilizes time so I've decided to use the Joda library, more specifically the Joda Time-JSP tags Version 1.1.1 (can be found here -> [www.joda.org/joda-time-jsptags/](http://www.joda.org/joda-time-jsptags/))

My code is correct as far as the site explains with

> 

at the begining of the page and

> <% pageContext.setAttribute("now", new org.joda.time.DateTime()); %>
>   < joda:format value="${now}" style="SM"/>

following after, in the body of the JSP page.

I am getting this error :

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> Stacktrace:
>           org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
>           org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
>           org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
>           org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
>           org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
>           org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
>           org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
>           org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
>           org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>           org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>           javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

I am using apache tomcat v.7 and I have the jsptags jar file in my WEB-INF/lib/ folder.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing some jar files in my WEB-INF/lib/ file: jstl-1.2.jar and joda-time-2.4.jar

(I had already included the joda-time-jsptags-1.1.1.jar)

I also imported java.util.Date, java.util.TimeZone, and org.joda.time.*

Hope this helps if anyone had a similar issue.